# Please help with simple test case in jasmine

Tags: protractor, jasmine

I am stuck with jasmine.
I read/youtubed/googled but seems like I am on the wrong track.

Here is what I have so far. I've used protractor --elementExplorer to pull items from http://www.angular.io:

```
> element.all(by.css('.nav-link')).getText()
[ '', 'FEATURES', 'DOCS', 'RESOURCES', 'EVENTS', 'BLOG' ]
```

Here is my test:

```
import { ElementFinder, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('angulario homepage verify list', function () { //Suite in Jasmine
    it('should check top 5 link buttons', function () { // Test in Jasmine
        browser.get('https://angular.io'); // Entering application url in browser
        element.all(by.css('.nav-link')).getText()); {
            //expect statement goes here
        });
    });
});
```

i am trying to ensure 5 links on the center top are present and it appears the elementExplorer return an Array... How do i use it to create my locator and expect statements?

Comment: too much code (we're not code fixers) and not code formatted.  please reduce scope and test smaller things and format your code

Comment: Have anyone found a solution to the above question? Please help, mee too stuck with the same problem.!

Comment: Did the advice in @alecxe's answer and the comments help you? If they didn't, you should ask a new question with your code, the HTML you are trying to check, and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You may just use `expect()` and `toEqual()` matcher:

```
browser.get('https://angular.io'); 
expect(element.all(by.css('.nav-link')).getText()).toEqual([
    '', 'FEATURES', 'DOCS', 'RESOURCES', 'EVENTS', 'BLOG' 
]);
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this and i get this error on visua studio code                        : [ts]
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'ObjectContaining<Promise<string>>'.
    Property 'jasmineMatches' is missing in type 'string[]'.
do i assign this statement to a variable of type array[]?

Comment: this is what worked for me....                                                                                
          expect(element.all(by.css('.nav-link')).getText()).toBeTruthy([
      '', 'FEATURES', 'DOCS', 'RESOURCES', 'EVENTS', 'BLOG' ]);

Comment: @user8816197 wait..no, the `toBeTruth‌y()` matcher is not actually gonna check the values of the texts - it is not an appropriate matcher in this case at all. You definitely need `toEqual()` to match the texts of the navigation links against your array of strings.

Comment: @user8816197 regarding your error - it looks like you need to install proper typings for jasmine: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15215.

Comment: could you please let me know what typings should i have... i will double check the conf file package.json as well... thanks in advance

Comment: sorry for delayed reply, after checking in few spots i have conflicting info:)   
    C:\Windows\System32>npm view jasmine version
    2.8.0 when i check the folder of my project under node - modules i can see 
  "_id": "@types/jasmine@2.6.2",  
  THEN if i look under my project folder package.json and i don'tsee any thing with jasmine types there.... Do i just create it?

Comment: thanks so much for your feedback,                                          
do you know where do i need to check the typings... is it in config.ts file? or package.json?                                                        protractorautomation@1.0.0 C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation
`-- protractor@5.2.0
  `-- jasminewd2@2.2.0

npm WARN protractorautomation@1.0.0 No repository field.

C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation\node_modules>npm install jasminewd

protractorautomation@1.0.0 C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation
`-- jasminewd@1.1.0

Comment: I was able to fix it by reinstalling the @types/jasmine and jasminewd2                  thank you for your help! I am still confused on other things but will try to post my questions in the separate thread.